# How to make a web link open directly on Google Play Store

Tags: javascript, android, webview, google-play, blogger

I have a blogger website using a template, www.aplitechstore.com.br, 
We have added many app links to download on Google Play, but they do not open in the Google Play Store app but on the website.
I want to change that, I want our app and website (in Webview mode) after clicking the link, open it in the Google Play Store app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As explained here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/22189/link-to-app-will-not-open-in-google-play), Google Play provides url protocol

```xml
market://details?id=<package_name>
```

**Applying on Blogger :**

Place the following javascript code at the bottom and before `</body>`. This will change Google Play links only on Android.

```xml
<script>
if (/(android)/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
  document.querySelectorAll('a[href]').forEach(function (link) {
    link.href = link.href.replace('https://play.google.com/store/apps/','market://');
  });
}
</script>
```

Comment: Don't work www.aplitechstore.com.br, the "market" it's only accepted in android development visual studio, the app is based on webview (using the mobile chrome browser)

Comment: Works perfectly, but I can't put on my website, I've tested all methods on the link you provide me, Can You Give me a Step-by-step

Comment: thank you I will, have you a paypal acc so can I pay you a Coffee